# How to handle several files based on one file? (GIT)

Tags: php, git, version-control

I'v a base file called `base.php` and I use it to generate several files with different names (`file1.php`, `file2.php`, `file3.php` etc)

for example,

base.php :

```
class Base
{
    public function baseFunction1(){
        do somethings
    }

    public function baseFunction2(){
        do somethings
    }
}
```

file1.php on project1:

```
<?php

class File1
{
    public function baseFunction1(){
        do somethings
    }

    public function baseFunction2(){
        do somethings
    }
    some other functions
}
```

file2.php on project2:

```
<?php

class File2
{
    public function baseFunction1(){
        do somethings
    }

    public function baseFunction2(){
        do somethings
    }
    some other functions
}
```

Now I update `base.php` file.

Is there any way to update other files using GIT?
I'm looking for a way that I do not have to compare and update all the files manually.

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you are looking for. Please take the time to review your question and add a few more details about your motivation. What it actually is you are looking for and why. Question: of you "generate" those files, then why do you have to "update" them by means of GIT, whatever you mean by that?

Comment: You can use `git cherry-pick` for picking up changes and merge them back to your original file.

Comment: I added more detail.

Comment: Why don’t you do it the right way and make an abstract class that all of your php files can extend, or a simple class with all your base functions and then, no matter what you just have to update that base class. Just a thought.

Comment: @muecas Thanks.The above example is a simple example
My projects have a more complex structure. Using Exstend is correct in this example, but it can not be used in my projects. I am looking for an external solution like GIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Git, you can use **`pre-commit` hook** to update other files automatically.

The idea is detect if `base.php` (or `file1.php` or `file2.php`) is changed, then update other two files with the same contents as the changed file.